# ActivityForResult doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I am new in android. I was making a sample. I was going to ask a user to turn on bluetooth. The ask form shows but onActivity result does not work. Why?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, RESULT_OK);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request code should be greater than Zero, but RESULT_OK = -1 so try to give Request code more than 0,

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 101);
```

[Src](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

RESULT_OK is -1 and startActivityForResult expects requestCode >=0.

RESULT_OK (added in API level 1)

```
int RESULT_OK
Standard activity result: operation succeeded.

Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)
```

Method startActivityForResult  (added in API level 1)

```
void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)

Parameters
intent  Intent: The intent to start.
requestCode int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

Throws
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
```

You should handle response as per requestCode.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Can use switch case also if more requestCode
        if (requestCode == 100) {
             // do something
        } else if (requestCode == 101) {
             // do something
        } else {
             // do something
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```